# Android WebView vs CustomTabs

Tags: android, android-webview, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

As a part of my project, I'm expected to load a webpage using a web view within the app.

I could either use WebView or CustomTabs but the favoured option was to go with WebView for the UI customisation that was possible.

The issue I found is that for the same URL, the content loaded on the WebView is different from that on the CustomTabs. I'm unsure why this happens and am keep on getting to know how I can observe the same content on both these implementations.

For the sake of an example, loading Facebook login screen looks different on these two implementation. Please find the screenshots below:

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyAHG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbhFF.png)

The content viewed on the CustomTab is what is desired. I would like to know how/what steps I need to take inorder to recreate the same experience on WebView as that of the CustomTabs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: WebView file upload is not working, Can I use CustomTabs? Is there any way to set user agent in CustomTabs?. I have posted question [here](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/330655005) please check and respond.